# BeanCreationException Issue when trying to run app in eclipse tomcat but works when I use maven and deploy it from local tomcat

Tags: javascript, eclipse, maven, tomcat

This is a rather strange issue that I've not seen yet. Context: This is a legacy project that I am trying to debug locally.

When trying to run my application from Eclipse I receive this error:

> SEVERE: Context initialization failed
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactoryA' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/config/application-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Conflicting persistence unit definitions for name 'PersistenceUnit': file:/wtpwebapps/{redacted}/WEB-INF/classes/, file:/C:/wtpwebapps/{redacted}/WEB-INF/classes/

The second exception is:

> SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener]
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactoryA' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/config/application-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Conflicting persistence unit definitions for name 'PersistenceUnit': file:/{redacted}/WEB-INF/classes/, file:/{redacted}/WEB-INF/classes/

I used a diff checker to check the paths for the 2nd exception and there's no difference

However when I don't use eclipse and just deploy it directly in tomcat after building the war file using maven from the CLI it works (although I have different issues, but at least it runs)

My colleagues don't know what's wrong with my Eclipse environment since they don't have any exception when trying to run it. It's supposed to run from the master branch unchanged.

Finally I am not experienced with Eclipse at all but that's what I have to work with.

Comment: Are you using Eclipse to deploy your workspace's copy to a copy of Tomcat that's already running this legacy project?

Comment: I make sure that Tomcat is stopped before trying to run it on Eclipse